# Probability that n numbers are in A and B

Tags: probability, statistics

We have set $A \subset \{1 , 2, ... ,49 \}$
it contains 6 numbers.
We cannot select same number multiple times.

We randomly select 10 numbers from $\{1 , 2, ... ,49 \}$. What is the probability that exactly 4 out of 6 numbers from A are also in these 10 seleced numbers?

My approach ( which is invadlid )

We want 4 out of 6 that is clearly binomial distribution.so

Let Z = probability that x is in A = $\frac{1}{36}$

let Y = probability that x is in B ( in 10 selected numbers ) = $\frac{1}{36}$

so
$C(6,4) \cdot ( Z \cdot Y )^{4} \cdot ( Z \cdot Y^{c})^{2}$

But this yields wrong result.

What is the right way how to calculate this?

Thanks you very much

Comment: Can we select the same number multiple times?

Comment: No we cannot, i will add it to question.

Comment: Not following your calculation.  The probability that a randomly selected number is in $A$ is $\frac {6}{36}$, not $\frac 1{36}$.  Similarly, you should get $\frac {10}{36}$ for $B$.  Also, the probabilities are not independent.  Having chosen, say, one element in $B$ the probability that the next choice is in $B$ is lower.

Comment: This is the *hypergeometric distribution*

Answer (score 1):

You need to caclulate the subsets of $\{1,2, ... 49\}$ that contain exactly $4$ elements of $A$. To construct such subsets so first we can choose $4$ out of the $6$ elements, which can be done in $\binom{6}{4}$ ways. Now choose $6$ numbers from the rest $43$ elements, which can be done in $\binom{43}{6}$. Obviously these two events are independent. So the wanted probability is:

$$\frac{\binom 64 \cdot \binom{43}{6}}{\binom{49}{10}}$$

Comment: why do we chose 6 out of 43 ?

Comment: @Johnyb Because we have $43$ elements not from $A$ and our subset should include $6$ of them.

Comment: @Johnyb: We choose $4$ from the $6$ prechosen and $6$ from the $43$ not prechosen.